# Access by type in std::tuple with duplicated types should produce compilation error

Tags: c++, c++14, std

According to the standard (or at least to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get)) the std::get for std::tuple shall:

> 5-8) Extracts the element of the tuple t whose type is T. Fails to compile unless the tuple has exactly one element of that type.

So I interpret that sentence such that this code does not compile:

```
std::tuple<int, int> my_record;
std::get<int>(my_record) = 10;
```

Because two identical types exist and I try to access the tuple by type. However, [both GCC an Clang correctly compile this code and produce the effect of modifying the first element](https://godbolt.org/z/YzorM9P8K).

Why? Am I misinterpreting the sentence on the reference? Is the reference wrong? Do GCC and Clang not respect the standard?

Comment: Fails to compile for me https://godbolt.org/z/c15Ef3MP9  Interesting it changes with compiler version.  clang 11.0.1 and gcc 10.3 fail to compile; higher version compile it.

Comment: libstdc++ seems indeed have a bug, libc++ passes  [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EGvGbvrWY) (error in library not the compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a GCC 11 bug, consider filing it. Here's the [revelant part of the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple#elem-5).

You see it in Clang because on gcc.godbolt.org it uses GCC's standard library by default. If you add `-stdlib=libc++` to use it's own standard library, it refuses to compile it.

Comment: Bug filed: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101427 ;)